# Transitioning from DotNetOpenAuth 3.4 to 4.2 - IProviderApplicationStore to IOpenIdApplicationStore

Tags: openid, dotnetopenauth, openid-provider

We are an OpenId Provider and our team is using DotNetOpenAuth 3.4 currently in production as the underlying OpenId Provider Service. We have implemented the IProviderApplicationStore interface, and used database tables to store the OpenIdAssociation and OpenIdNonce.

Now we want to move to version 4.2, but this implementation now uses the IOpenIdApplicationStore interface. This interface inherits the ICryptoStore interface instead of the IAssociationStore interface.

Can someone tell  me how to migrate the Provider code and the OpenIdAssociation table to using the CryptoStore?

Any other things we should look out for?